# Update statement where one column depends on another updated column

Tags: t-sql

I want to update two columns in my table, one of them depends on the calculation of another updated column. The calculation is rather complex, so I don't want to repeat that every time, I just want to use the newly updated value.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    A int,
    B int,
    C int,
    D int
)

INSERT INTO test VALUES (0, 0, 5, 10)

UPDATE test
    SET 
        B = C*D * 100,
        A = B / 100
```

So my question, is this even possible to get `50` as the value for column A in just one query?
Another option would be to use persistent computed columns, but will that work when I have dependencies on another computed column?

Comment: I just found out that it is not possible to have computed columns that depend on each other

Comment: If you can calculate out the values on the backend first (presuming there is a backend), this would really be the best route to go, given that you can't insert/update values based upon other values that are being inserted/updated at the same time.  The other option would be to do something like insert the value initially, grab the PK of the data (as well as the chunk of data you need for the calculation) that was just inserted, and immediately update it after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant achieve what you are trying to in a single query.This is due to a Concept called <kbd>All At Once Operations</kbd> which translates to "In SQL Server, Operations which appears in Same logical Phase are evaluated at the same time.."..

Below operations wont yield result you are expecting

```
insert into table1
(t1,t1+100,t1+200)-- sql wont use new t1 incremented value
```

sames goes with update as well

```
  update t1
   set t1=t1*100
       t2=t1   --sql wont use t1 updated value(*100)
```

**References:**
[TSQL Querying by Itzik Ben-Gan](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=FZlCAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT64&lpg=PT64&dq=All-at-Once%20Operations%20in%20T-SQL&source=bl&ots=S5XXIg-9Mb&sig=dycsMi7Fdoy9D5VCchBljYGI8Aw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJwpy59MjNAhWCrY8KHW0vDf4Q6AEIOjAF#v=onepage&q=All-at-Once%20Operations%20in%20T-SQL&f=false)